# wait() system call - does the child ignore this?

Tags: c, concurrency, wait, system-calls

So I've seen the following code during my revision. I know the wait() causes the parent to wait for the child to stop but I have a few questions regarding this.

Firstly, when the child is created, is my assumption corrected that the parent continues, changes the x value and THEN waits after the if-statement?

Secondly, when the child carries on execution and gets to wait(), what happens? Is this ignored as it has nothing to wait for?

```
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <unistd.h>
       int main() {
         int x = 1;
          pid_t pid = fork();
         if (pid == 0) {
             x = x * 2;
         } else if (pid > 0) {
             x = 3;
         }
         wait();
         // Print the value of x to the console
         printf("%d\n",x);
       }
```

Comment: Have you tried? Did the program seem to hang (regarding your second question)?

Comment: Yes (regarding your first question).

Comment: The declaration of [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) is `pid_t wait(int *stat_loc)`, and while it is permitted to pass 0 or NULL in place of a pointer, you do have to pass something as an argument.  Of course, you'd need `#include <sys/wait.h>` included for the compiler to be able to warn you — but you should not be compiling code such that you can use functions without a prototype in scope.  You don't need `#include <sys/types.h>` on current POSIX systems (it gets included automatically; it was necessary in original POSIX — 1988, 1990).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can experiment calling wait() at the begin of child execution. Once there is no children in this process, the callling is simple ignored.